jQuery.Deferred exception: dateFormat is not defined ReferenceError: dateFormat is not defined
I am trying to upgrade dateformat package which was 3.0.3 in my package.json
I have a following method which is throwing above error
  function GenerateTimestamp() {
      return dateFormat(new Date(), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss.l");
  }

Any idea what change i required?
version of package.json I have tried are 4.x.x
My package.json is as following
{
  "name": "my.web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootbox": "5.5.3",
    "bootstrap": "3.4.1",
    "dateformat": "3.0.3",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "4.17.49",
    "genesys-cloud-webrtc-sdk": "9.2.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "4.3.0",
    "gulp-sass": "5.1.0",
    "sass": "1.79.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "3.0.2",
    "highcharts": "6.2.0",
    "jquery": "3.7.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "1.13.3",
    "jquery-validation": "1.21.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "4.0.0",
    "merge-stream": "2.0.0",
    "moment": "2.30.1",
    "purecloud-platform-client-v2": "204.1.0",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "1.1.4",
    "url-search-params": "1.1.0",
    "uglify-js": "3.19.3",
    "yargs": "15.3.1",
    "summernote": "0.8.18"
  }
}

my gulp file looks like following
/// <binding BeforeBuild='build' Clean='clean' Minify='min' />
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rimraf = require('rimraf'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass')),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    merge = require('merge-stream'),
    configuration = require('yargs').default('configuration', 'Debug').argv.configuration;

var paths = {
    webroot: './wwwroot/'
};

paths.js = paths.webroot + 'js/**/*.js';
paths.minJs = paths.webroot + 'js/**/*.min.js';
paths.css = paths.webroot + 'css/**/*.css';
paths.minCss = paths.webroot + 'css/**/*.min.css';
paths.concatJsDest = paths.webroot + 'js/site.min.js';
paths.concatCssDest = paths.webroot + 'css/site.min.css';
paths.libJs = paths.webroot + 'lib/';
paths.npm = 'node_modules/';

var jsLibraries = {
    'bootbox': {
        '*.*': ''
    },
    'bootstrap': {
        'dist/**/*.*': ''
    },
    'dateformat': {
        'lib/*.*': ''
    },
    'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker': {
        'build/**/*.*': ''
    },
    'genesys-cloud-webrtc-sdk': {
        'dist/*.*': ''
    },
    'highcharts': {
        '*.*': ''
    },
    'jquery': {
        'dist/*.*': ''
    },
    'jquery-ui-dist': {
        '*.*': ''
    },
    'jquery-validation': {
        'dist/*.*': ''
    },
    'jquery-validation-unobtrusive': {
        'dist/*.*': ''
    },
    'moment': {
        'min/*.*': ''
    },
    'purecloud-platform-client-v2': {
        'dist/web-cjs/*.*': ''
    },
    '@aspnet/signalr': {
        'dist/browser/*.*': ''
    },
    'url-search-params': {
        'build/*.*': ''
    },
    'summernote': {
        'dist/**/*.*': ''
    }
};

gulp.task('clean:jslib', function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.libJs, cb);
});

gulp.task('clean:js', gulp.series('clean:jslib', function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatJsDest, cb);
}));

gulp.task('lib:js', gulp.series('clean:js', function () {
    var streams = [];
    for (var library in jsLibraries) {
        for (var libraryItem in jsLibraries[library]) {
            streams.push(gulp.src(paths.npm + library + '/' + libraryItem)
                .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.libJs + library.substr(library.indexOf('/') + 1) + '/' + jsLibraries[library][libraryItem])));
        }
    }

    return merge(streams);
}));

gulp.task('min:js', gulp.series('lib:js', function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.js, '!' + paths.minJs], { base: '.' })
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
}));

gulp.task('clean:css', function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.css, cb);
});

gulp.task('sass:css', gulp.series('clean:css', function () {
    return gulp.src('Styles/site.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + 'css/'));
}));

gulp.task('min:css', gulp.series('sass:css', function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.css, '!' + paths.minCss])
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
}));

gulp.task('min', gulp.series('min:js', 'min:css'));

gulp.task('build', gulp.series('min'));


Are you importing the dateFormat function? Can you share a minimal version of the package.json and that js file?

@vzsoares I don't see any importing code in the js file where above function is added. I am sharing the package.json

I don't think i have enough information to fully answer the question. How are you invoking the function? How is project being bundled? For now my suspicion is that dateFormat is not being imported. How to import really depends on the project. Look forward into importing/including that module.

@vzsoares added gulp file as well

basically i am trying to upgrade the js libraries one by one so that they are not breaking any implementation.

Also one thing I noticed is dateformat folder is not getting created in lib folder after i restore the package.json

Add :
const dateFormat = require('dateformat');

Or
Update your package.json and install the correct version:
bash
npm install dateformat@4.6.3 --save

In your package.json:
"dateformat": "4.6.3"


I am having this in my .net core project where I do use restore pacakges to update my libraries.
